# Fix for php 5.3.9 libxsl security "bug" fix

Tags: security, debian, php, xslt

just this morning i updated my debian server to php [5.3.9](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.9) , change log (last item in list) has a fix for this [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54446) and now when running any hosted site using XSL transforms i get:

```
Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): Can't set libxslt security properties, not doing transformation for security reasons
```

I'm not using any `<sax:output>` tags in my xslt at all.

Does anybody have any information on this, current chatter about it is thin, so i'm i little lost.

Using the suggestion about switching ini settings on and off either side of ->transformToXml():

```
ini_set("xsl.security_prefs", XSL_SECPREFS_NONE)
```

or

```
$xsl->setSecurityPreferences(XSL_SECPREFS_NONE)
```

brings me back to the same error

Many thanks.

**Progress:**
 - Upgrading libxml and recompiling libxslt against the new version was a good suggestion, though has not fixed the issue.
 - Compiling the latest php5.3 snapshot does not fix the issue.

**Solution:**
I'm unsure what actually solved this, very sorry for anyone else having the same problem. firstly i upgraded libxml, then applied a few patches, then went into php source for the xsl parser and added some debugging and a few tweaks, after a few compiles getting the configure args right the error went away and wasn't reproducible.
I would definitely recommend upgrading libxml as Petr suggested below and then grabbing the latest snapshot from php.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your libxml extension. (2.7.7 -> 2.7.8 might have solved the problem in my case)

Comment: phpinfo() shows libxslt version: 1.1.26 compiled against libxml version 2.7.8

Answer (score 2):

I wish this was better documented (see php bug #61233), but from the source code it looks like the method name for PHP 5.4+ is "setSecurityPrefs" instead of "setSecurityPreferences" and the constant is "XSL_SECPREF_NONE" instead of "XSL_SECPREFS_NONE" (as opposed to what you can read in a comment for bug #54446). Altough, I would rather use 0 in case they change their mind about the spelling.

Right now I'm trying something like that :

```
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4', '<')) {
        $oldval = ini_get('xsl.security_prefs');
        if ($oldval != '0') {
            $oldval = ini_set('xsl.security_prefs', '0');
            if ($oldval === false)
                ;//manage the error
        }
    } else
        $oldval = $xsltproc->setSecurityPrefs(0);
```

and after the transform:

```
    if ($oldval != 0 && $oldval != '0') {
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4', '<'))
            ini_set('xsl.security_prefs', $oldval);
        else
            $xsltproc->setSecurityPrefs($oldval);
    }
```